# Close RabbitMQ channel while in BasicAcks

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a pool of RabbitMQ channels under one connection. And I'm trying to implement the `Publisher Confirms` feature. I've built the pool in a way that it creates new channels as demand for channels increases. But now, I have to manage the closure of these channels too.

I plan to implement a solution like in the [RabbitMQ tutorials](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/9eb4edbef16b4e9c24352f92cc34d700c21d3669/dotnet/PublisherConfirms/PublisherConfirms.cs#L80) using a `outstandingConfirms` list.

I came to the problem that I have to somehow close a channel (when I'm above my 'soft' threshold of objects in the pool) when the last message in a channel is `ack-ed` or `nack-ed`.

As you can see in the code below, the `sender` parameter is actually the channel itself, I thought I could use this directly to close the channel if there are no pending messages anymore. But I faced the fact that channels should not be used by more than one thread simultaneously. This same channel will be available in the pool and can be picked up by the application for usage.

These are the event subscriptions:

```
protected void OnBasicAcks(object sender, BasicAckEventArgs e)
{
    //sender = channel object
    //todo close channel after all pending messages (n)acked
}

protected void OnBasicNacks(object sender, BasicNackEventArgs e)
{
    //sender = channel object
    //todo close channel after all pending messages (n)acked
}
```

Also [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consumer-callbacks-and-ordering) I can read that blocking operations are allowed in callback handlers:

> As of version 3.5.0 application callback handlers can invoke blocking
>   operations (such as IModel.QueueDeclare or  IModel.BasicCancel)

But does this also apply to the closure of the channel itself?

In short, this is my problem. My questions are:

1. Can I use the channel passed through the `sender` parameter directly to do operations like `IModel.Close()`?
2. I just want to prevent getting deadlocks on channels or other weird stuff. Any advice or best practice for my problem?
3. And something completely different: can I create a new channel while I'm in the `OnBasicAcks` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest RabbitMQ.Client (v5.1, I think), the callbacks are all invoked on the ThreadPool using *async* so you're generally okay calling those methods in callbacks. I would, however, avoid hijacking the callback thread to do any long-running tasks as they are managed per-channel by the RabbitMQ client.

So, to answer specifically.

1. Should be fine, looking at the source code, it doesn't lock anything that would prevent close from being called. Just be wary of anything in *your* code that would deadlock.
2. It's best to control access to the session in your own code so that you aren't calling a single channel from multiple threads expecting anything to happen in a specific order.
3. Should work fine, you're on a TPL task thread, so no reason it shouldn't work.

If you want more details on how the client works, you can look at the [source](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client), particularly the [ModelBase.cs](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/impl/ModelBase.cs) file, and the asynchronous worker service it creates for callbacks.